# Need help creating an loop in R for a casino player

Tags: r

I'm having problems creating an loop containing a casinoplayer that starts with capital 1. 
She plays the casino X times until she reaches capital 5 or 0. 
I need to do 1000 simulations. 
If I want to see how the results change when she starts with capital 2 is it just to change capital <- 2.

So far my code looks like this. cow = Chance of winning

```
cow <- 0.5 if (runif(1) < cow) { capital <- 1 capital <- capital + 1 } else { capital <- capital - 1 }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently did something very similar (not gambling, but basketball shooting practice - the idea is the same). Have a look at my code below.

the 'gamble' function plays the game once, until capital reaches 0 or 5, and records whether you won or lost. It returns a data frame that contains the outcome of the game, the amount of gambles made, and the percentage of gambles won (which should in the long run be very close to your probability of winning a round).

The 'simulate.games' function then simulates this game a thousand times. If you want to modify the amount that can be one in each round you can simply modify the 'plus' and 'minus' variables during the while-loop.

Hope this helps!

```
library(dplyr)

gamble <- function(upper = 5, lower = 0, plus = 1, minus = -1, prob = .5) {
    # prob represents the probability of winning one round

    capital <- 1
    won <- 0
    count <- 0
    while(capital > lower & capital < upper){
        count <- count + 1
        game <- sample(x = c(plus, minus), size = 1, prob = c(prob, 1 - prob))
        capital <- capital + game
        if(game == plus){
            won <- won + 1
            }
        }
    result <- ifelse(capital <= lower, 0, 1) # 0 represents a loss, 1 represents a victory
    tbl_df(data.frame(result = result, count = count, pct = won / count))
}

simulate.games <- function(num.games = 1000, ...) {
    # initialize
    outcome <- gamble(...)
    for(i in 1:(num.games-1)){
        outcome <- rbind(outcome, gamble(...))
    }
    outcome
}

# typical usage:
# simulate.games(num.games = 1000, upper = 5, lower = 0, plus = 1, minus = -1, prob = .5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do something:

```
#Here you have the definition of the function

gamble <- function(capital, upper=5, lower=0, cow=0.5){
  while(capital < upper & capital>lower){
    if(runif(1)>cow){
        capital <- capital +1
    } else capital <- capital -1
  }
  capital
}

# Here you have the call to the function and the cycle 

simulations <- 1000 # declare here the number of simulations
results <- c(1:simulations)
for(i in seq_along(results)){
   results[i] <- gamble(1)
}
```

The result ('results') is a vector of numeric containing the values of the capital in the end of each simulation (0 or 5). Hope this helps